# Responsive Design Testing using TestCafe

Tags: responsive-design, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, galen

As part of evaluation for a new test automation framework, I am looking to see if we can automate testing for responsive designs of a website. To give you a better idea, today we use the GALEN framework to do this. Our tests cover things like pixel points, height, width, colors, sizes of containers, positioning of page elements (Above, below, side ) etc. We create our WebDriver object in Java-Selenium and then pass it on to Galen for this testing.

For assertions we use a spec file where we mention the visual/ responsive design requirements. Things GALEN can do for us are listed here: http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-spec-language-guide/

I am trying to see if I can accomplish this using testCafe but I am not sure where to start from; I did an initial search on testCafe site but didn’t find anything that is GALEN like. Just wondering if testCafe can be extended to GALEN? I am also open to other ideas as to how I can accomplish responsive testing. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With TestCafe, you can resize browsers and make screenshots. Besides, we are planning to support [Visual Regression Testing](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1207) in the nearest future.
At the moment TestCafe does not support any special syntax for comparing element properties. However, you can still check any DOM element property using [element snapshots](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#dom-node-snapshot) and [Client Functions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/)

As far as I understand, GALEN was built over Selenium, so I'm not sure that it exposes any API that can be used in TestCafe without Selenium.

Anyway, you can [create a feature request](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) in the TestCafe repository